# Creating Tycho product error: Missing requirement

Tags: eclipse, rcp, tycho

I'm new to Tycho. I am trying to create a product using Tycho, but every time I run it, I run into the following error:

```
Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: RCPplugin.RCPplugin 0.0.1.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: RCPplugin.RCPplugin 0.0.1.qualifier requires  'org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.7.2.dist-8R9GFpOFUdy-521934]' but it could not be found
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.": ["Unable to satisfy dependency from RCPplugin.RCPplugin 0.0.1.qualifier to org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.7.2.dist-8R9GFpOFUdy-521934].", "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable."] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.": ["Unable to satisfy dependency from RCPplugin.RCPplugin 0.0.1.qualifier to org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.7.2.dist-8R9GFpOFUdy-521934].", "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable."]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.": ["Unable to satisfy dependency from RCPplugin.RCPplugin 0.0.1.qualifier to org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.7.2.dist-8R9GFpOFUdy-521934].", "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable."]
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.AbstractResolutionStrategy.newResolutionException(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.ProjectorResolutionStrategy.resolve(ProjectorResolutionStrategy.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveProject(P2ResolverImpl.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveProject(P2ResolverImpl.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.doResolvePlatform(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.resolveDependencies(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:61)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:274)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    ... 11 more
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Did you tell Tycho where to look for dependencies? Unlike in Maven, Tycho does not have a default repository where it looks for dependencies. You need to configure this search scope - the so-called target platform - explicitly, e.g. with

```
<repository>
  <id>eclipse-indigo</id>
  <layout>p2</layout>
  <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo</url>
</repository>
```

More options to configure the target platform can be found [here in the documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reference_Card).