# eclipse RCP maven/tycho missing requirement 'bundle org.eclipse.e4.core.di'

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, rcp, tycho

There is an Eclipse RCP/IDE-Plug-in project which depends on several Eclipse Modules like `org.eclipse.e4.core.di` or `org.eclipse.core.runtime`.

This project compiles in a Eclipse IDE for Committers environment with a `.target` file for dependency setup.

I want to add a headless maven/tycho build for this project resulting in errors as follows:

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: org.myplugin.someservice 1.0.0
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: org.myplugin.someservice 1.0.0 requires 'bundle org.eclipse.e4.core.di 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

The project setup looks like this:

```
releng/
     org.myplugin.releng/
          pom.xml (contains tycho-plugins def, modules, target ref)
     org.myplugin.target/
          Neon.target
          pom.xml (contains 'eclipse-target-definition')
plugins/
    org.myplugin.someservice/
          pom.xml
          META-INF/
              MANIFEST.MF (contains reference to org.eclipse.e4.core.di)
```

I've used the Tutorial from Lars Vogel (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#exercise-using-a-target-platform-for-the-build) for the base setup and understanding.

The contents of the target file are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?><target name="Neon" sequenceNumber="43">
    <locations>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.eclipse.platform.sdk" version="4.6.3.M20170301-0400"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.pde.feature.group" version="3.12.3.v20170301-0400"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.pde.source.feature.group" version="3.12.3.v20170301-0400"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.platform.ide" version="4.6.3.M20170301-0400"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="3.12.0.v20170209-1843"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group" version="4.6.3.v20170301-0400"/>
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.6"/>
        </location>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.cdo.epp.feature.group" version="4.5.0.v20160607-1511"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group" version="2.12.0.v20160526-0356"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.compare.diagram.papyrus.feature.group" version="3.2.1.201608311750"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.xtext.sdk.feature.group" version="2.10.0.v201605250459"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.sdk.feature.group" version="1.10.0.201606071959"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.notation.sdk.feature.group" version="1.10.0.201606071631"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.uml2.sdk.feature.group" version="5.2.3.v20170227-0935"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.compare.ide.ui.feature.group" version="3.2.1.201608311750"/>
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon"/>
        </location>
    </locations>
</target>
```

This catches mostly what my Eclipse Installation Information prints out about the installed software.

The `target/pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.myplugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.myplugin.releng</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../org.myplugin.releng/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.myplugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.myplugin.target</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-target-definition</packaging>
</project>
```

The `releng/pom.xml` is quite big and specifies all maven/tycho plugins, the target file to use for dependency resolution, target platforms and all plugins and features as modules.

For one failing plugin the pom.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.myplugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.myplugin.releng</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../org.myplugin.releng/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.myplugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.myplugin.someservice</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
</project>
```

I've read many similar question here on stackoverflow and tried many of the fixes:

- removing the version tag target/pom.xml,
- removing the relative path,
- using pom instead of eclipse-target-definition
- and some more

Nothing worked. So what am I missing here?

**EDIT:**
As I understood the `releng/pom.xml` should setup tycho plugins and maven stuff. Executing the `mvn clean verfiy` command should then build the solution while the specified Neon.target definition in `releng/pom.xml` takes the `target/pom.xml` and `target/Neon.target` to get the Eclipse Environment (including `org.eclipse.e4.core.di`, and `org.eclipse.core` stuff) plus any further defined dependencies.

**EDIT2:**
My `eclipse-target-definition` plugin is configured like this:

```
<profile>
    <id>Neon.target</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <xtext-version>2.10.0</xtext-version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includePackedArtifacts>true</includePackedArtifacts>
                    <target>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>org.myplugin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>org.myplugin.target</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                            <classifier>org.myplugin.target</classifier>
                        </artifact>
                    </target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

**EDIT3:** I'm using Tycho Version 1.0.0

**EDIT4** Fixed a typo in `target/pom.xml`.

Comment: Can you open your `Neon.target` in the Eclipse *Target Editor*. Wait till Eclipse has resolved the target platform and then double-check on the *Contents* tab whether `org.eclipse.e4.core.di` is indeed included in your target platform.

Comment: OK, your `Neon.target` really **does** contain `org.eclipse.e4.core.di` (just double-checked myself). But does your `org.myplugin.someservice` plug-in have you the [target-platform-configuration](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#Target_files)  Maven plug-in configured in its `pom.xml` (or one of its parents)?

Comment: I appended the configuration of the target-platform-configuration plugin as EDIT2. This config is in the parent pom.xml from org.myplugin.releng.

Comment: Three remarks: **First**, the `<classifier>` of `org.myplugin.target` looks wrong; AFAICT from the `org.myplugin.target` POM, the `.target` file is deployed without a classifier (double-check this in your `~/.m2/repository/`). **Second**, is your `.target` file really called `org.myplugin.target.target`?  [Tycho expects it to be named `{project.artifactId}.target`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Packaging_Types#eclipse-target-definition). **Third**, is the `Neon.target` profile active when building? (Use `mvn help:active-profiles` or `mvn help:effective-pom` to check.)

Comment: Ok, so:
**First**: I didn't know that the classifier has to be also specified in the `org.myplugin.target` POM. Where can I read this up? (After removing it from `org.myplugin.releng` POM it still fails)
**Second**: The `{project.artifactId}` is `org.myplugin.target`, the target file therefor is called `org.myplugin.target.target` (yeah, it's ugly)
**Third**: It fails with these commands with the same `Missing Requierement ...` error.

Comment: **First**: You don’t have to use a `<classifier>` anywhere. In your `eclipse-target-definition` project, the `.target` file is the *primary* artifact. Hence, it does not have a classifier. Also, there is a mismatch between the version numbers used: `1.0.0.alpha-SNAPSHOT` vs. `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. Also, do you really run your build with `-P Neon.target` to activate the `<profile>`?

Comment: Thank you, I forgot the `-P Neon.target` option in my build command. To be honest, I can't remember in any tutorial or the eclipse wiki pages to read about that option. Thank you for pointing that out. The version mismatch was just a typo.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I’ve condensed this into a proper answer (with a bit of Best Practice advice) which you can up-vote, so others don’t have to wade though all these comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run Maven with `-P Neon.target` to activate your `<profile>`; otherwise your `target-platform-configuration` won’t be part of the build.

Personally, I would **always** have a default `target-platform-configuration` outside any `<profile>`. This could be, e.g., a target definition for the current release of Eclipse (as of this writing: Oxygen). I would only use ` for *unusual* target definitions like older Eclipse releases (in your case: Neon). But that’s just my personal best practice.

Answer (score -1):

Actually I solved my problem, but not like I would have expected. I assume it is not like it should work but here is how it works now:

I added to the `org.myplugin.releng/pom.xml` parent pom the following config according to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489527/creating-tycho-product-error-missing-requirement):

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>neon</id>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I did that before, but missed that I already had a *repositories* section elsewhere in the pom.xml which caused it to fail and got lost of that track in my rage :D

Actually I still believe that it should get that information from the target file. I noticed on the successful build, that the **target file is evaluated after the parent pom** leading to the situation that it requires all dependencies before even processing the target definition file.

I bet something is still wrong with my configuration, but at least it builds now. If someone has any idea though it would relief me somehow :)

Comment: You are right: The `<repository>` should not be necesary; the `eclipse-target-definition` should do all the work. “[T]hat the target file is evaluated after the parent pom” is to be expected, but before *building* **any** projects Tycho tries to *resolve* the target platform of **every** project. In order to do that, all (not yet built) `eclipse-target-definition` projects must strictly adhere to [the naming convention for the `.target` file](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Packaging_Types#eclipse-target-definition) so that Tycho can locate the target file in your project directory.